# Py + iOS + FFMPEG(libx264) "height not divisible by 2" & "while opening encoder - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"

Tags: python, appium, mobile-automation, ios, behave

Background :

- I have automated test suite in which I am trying to record video [for failed tests]on iOS using MacOS with M1
- Its working as expected on local and observing failures while running tests from Jenkins

Problem statment:

- Observing few mentioned errors & Unable to record video when execution has been triggered from Jenkins job

Errors :

1. FFMPEG (libx264) "height not divisible by 2"
2. FFMPEG (libx264) "width not divisible by 2"
3. Error while opening encoder - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
4. Screen capture process did not start within 5000ms

If anyone has found working solution to fixed this issue, please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

- Basically, property *'video'* type `h264` needs even dimensions. This filter will:

  1. Divide the original height and width by 2 and round it up to the nearest pixel
  2. Multiply it by 2 again, to make it an even number
- To solve this we can add/use properties like pad, crop or scale

  1. I fixed it by using 'videoScale'
  2. Solution 1 : could be subtract one (-1) from the resolution number to have a even number for either height or width. In few cases for both too.
  3. Example : `videoScale="320:-1"` OR `videoScale="-1:320"` But sometimes this also could get failed, because while converting it could endup calculating float number instead of absolute number
  4. Solution 2 : could be the working solution for all the time. Solution is to calculate the height and width own way and provide to methods to use. Hence method will get exactly what its looking for
  5. Example : `videoScale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"`

Let me know if you have fixed using pad or crop